# Rendering a net shaped mesh in a cloth simulation

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

Im trying to drape a net - like mesh ( a plane with a wireframe modifier ) onto my skeleton model, kind of like a poncho, in the hope that i can use the character in an animation. However I can't even simulate it without blender and my PC freezing.

I have tried using simpler collision shapes, but it doesn't really help much.

Does anyone have any suggestions for trying such a thing? I think the problem obviously points to the amount of polygons in a wireframe net shape, are there any easier ways to go about adding this to my skeleton?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your net mesh look like? If you want to apply cloth sim to a more dense mesh I would look into using a surface deform modifier.

Comment: Is the cloth modifier *before* the wireframe in the modifier stack?

Comment: Hi Chris, Ive added an image of the basic net, it uses a wireframe modifier on a subdivided plane. I have tried simple simulations even with just a UV sphere and it still can't handle it. My pc spec isnt bad but it could be that as well.  I will have a look into sub deform. Thanks!

Comment: I always put the cloth modifier last in the stack lemon, is this right?

Comment: Should try to set it before. You'll have less cloth calculations doing that and the final geometry will be nearly the same.